# SyntaxError: malformed hexadecimal character escape sequence

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get current working directory in PHP like below

```
$path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
debug_to_console ('path'.$path);
```

and function for log is like below

```
function debug_to_console( $data ) {
    $output = $data;
    if ( is_array( $output ) )
        $output = implode( ',', $output);

    echo "<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: " . $output . "' );</script>";
}
```

its giving me error in console like below

> SyntaxError: malformed hexadecimal character escape sequence

can anyone please correct me whats the wrong in it?
Thanks

Comment: Is that a JavaScript error or a PHP error? What "console" are you getting the message on? Please post the complete error message which probably includes a line number that the error is on.

Comment: @Dave console means browser console and I think its PHP error.

Comment: If it's the browser console it won't be an error from PHP. Please post the exact and complete error.